# Problema ao retornar uma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql

Por que quando executo a query abaixo, ele retorna registros:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dadf332.numped)) AS qtdped,   
DATE_FORMAT(dadf331.datlan, '%d/%m/%Y') AS datavenda 
FROM dadf331, dadf332 
WHERE dadf331.numped =  dadf332.numped
AND tipped = 0 
AND dadf331.datlan >= '2018-04-01' 
AND dadf331.datlan <= '2018-04-03' 

qtdped  datavenda   
------  ------------
24      02/04/2018
```

Ele retorna registro no dia 02, porem se eu executo a query até dia 02, ele nao retorna nada?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dadf332.numped)) AS qtdped,
DATE_FORMAT(dadf331.datlan, '%d/%m/%Y') AS datavenda
FROM dadf331, dadf332 
WHERE dadf331.numped = dadf332.numped 
AND tipped = 0
AND dadf331.datlan >= '2018-04-01' 
AND dadf331.datlan <= '2018-04-02'

qtdped  datavenda  
------  -----------
     0  (NULL)
```

Comment: Provavelmente o campo `dadf331.datlan` é `datetime` e possui horas no registro. Deve funcionar se você fizer a restrição assim: `... AND dadf331.datlan <= '2018-04-02 23:59:59'`

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza realmente ele é datetime, não tinha me ligado, e seu usar DATE_FORMAT(datlan, '%Y/%m/%d') >= DATE_FORMAT('2018-04-02', '%Y/%m/%d')

Comment: Isso. Deve funcionar também, mas deteriora um pouco a performance, neh?!

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza ah sim funcionou, é porque eu passo essa data como parâmetro, através de 2 inputs, e no input só manda a data

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o [**`DATE_ADD`**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) para contemplar a os registros que incluem hora no seu intervalo.

Então, você adiciona um dia na data final do intervalo (que vem sem hora) e busca os registros anteriores a essa nova data.

Assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(dadf332.numped)) AS qtdped,
    DATE_FORMAT(dadf331.datlan, '%d/%m/%Y') AS datavenda
FROM dadf331, dadf332 
WHERE dadf331.numped = dadf332.numped 
    AND tipped = 0
    AND dadf331.datlan >= '2018-04-01' 
    AND dadf331.datlan < DATE_ADD('2018-04-02', INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Espero que ajude.